# How to restrict access to a MySQL account to a single computer?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with users. However I am worried that they might share their account data to third-parties and other poeple might have access to the account.

My main idea is to restrict the account, so 1 computer can use it and access from other machines would be impossible.

The login form is in C# program.

Is there a way to make something like that? I'll try to answer all questions. :)

(I'm sorry for any grammar errors or too little details. I'm exhausted.)

Comment: Are you using AWS? if so you can only add the ip address you want to give access to the db

Answer (score 1):

When creating user accounts on MySql you give both a username and a hostname.

For example,

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' ...
```

makes an admin user that can only get in from the same machine.

In the same way, you could create an account like this:

```
CREATE USER 'altzero'@'10.11.12.13' ...
```

that can only access MySql from the machine with that IP address.

See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html